# Setting WCF Endpoint address at runtime?

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration

If I have the following:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(); 
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://xxx:pppp/MyService")); 

MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
```

How can  I set the endpoint bindingConfiguration? If it helps my app.config is set to:

```
<endpoint address="http://xxx:pppp/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary/ManagementService/"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IManagementService"
          contract="ServiceReference.IManagementService">
        <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
</endpoint>
```

However I'm looking to let the user configure this before running the client.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple fix!! Sorry to ask a silly question!

```
binding = new WSHttpBinding("WSHttpBinding_IManagementService");
```

Answer (score 0):

To set your binding administratively you need to add a binding section to your app.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>

  {...}

  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IManagementService" {other parameters ...} />
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  {...}

</system.serviceModel>
```

And if you do not feel confortable with the manual editing, you can use the WCF Service Configuration Editor which you can find in the Visual Studio menu Tools>WCF Service Configuration Editor.